# How can I check if the name isalpha() in the setter of a class property?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

can anyone help me out with this requirement? I have been trying to fix it, but not successful.
I would really appreciate if someone can help me out thanks.

`name`: property - returns capitalized name and setter checks the name isalpha() and if true store the name in the object otherwise store ‘Unknown’

`eid`: property - returns eid zero filled up to 4 spaces and setter will assign ‘9999’ if the length is zero, otherwise store the eid.

here is my code.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, eid):
        self.name = name
        self.eid = eid

    def set_name(self, name):
        if name.isalpha():
            self.__name = name
        else:
            self.__name = 'Unknown'

    def set_eid(self, eid):
        if self.eid.isalpha():
            self.eid = eid
        else:
            self.eid = "9999"

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_eid(self):
        return self.eid

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s: %s " % (self.eid, self.name)

def main():

    empName = input('Name')
    eid = input('Id')
    employeeInfo = Employee(empName, eid)

    print(employeeInfo.__str__())

main()
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the `@property` decorator. [Here's a tutorial on that.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

Comment: You didn't use either `def set_name(...` nor `def set_eid(...`?

Comment: I have been trying to fix that in many different ways, but the program still doesn't show 'Unknown ' and '9999' if user doesn’t put anything in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to define a property attribute. If you want a tutorial, use Google (for example [this one on Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)), but here's a quick example for a similar situation. If `name` is not alphabetical, it's set to `None`.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name if name.isalpha() else None

boxer = Person('Clay')
print(boxer.name)  # -> Clay
boxer.name = 'Ali'
print(boxer.name)  # -> Ali
boxer.name = ''
print(boxer.name)  # -> None
```